# What are the characteristics of solid carbon dioxide on the Martian poles?

Tags: planetary-atmosphere, mars, weather, thermodynamics

When carbon dioxide forms on Mars is it like ice or snow? How dense is newly formed solid carbon dioxide? Would more carbon dioxide form inside a pit vs a flat plain?

[How thick or deep does solid carbon dioxide accumulate on Mars?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/28232/how-thick-or-deep-does-solid-carbon-dioxide-accumulate-on-mars)

https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31724/martian-carbon-dioxide-turbine-oxygen-generator

Comment: Snow is ice. I imagine that the ices of the poles have at least *some* texture to them—possibly snow-like. I mean, they can't possibly be mirror-smooth.

Comment: It does snow dry ice on Mars, at least it was observed once on it's south pole.   https://www.space.com/17583-mars-snow-carbon-dioxide-discovery.html    A cool question - pun not intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Earth we know of frozen carbon dioxide as "dry ice." If shaved, it could exist as "dry ice snow." On Mars the dry ice snow could precipitate, then become compressed into dry ice. It would probably be a stiffly packed granular solid.
I had only heard of "water ice" on Mars. Check the article on kottke.org  Link:  https://kottke.org/18/12/a-massive-ice-filled-crater-on-mars